# How can I find and edit the HTML file on Shopify?

Tags: html, shopify

Sorry if this is an extremely basic question. I am new to Shopify but know my way around HTML/CSS.

I am in need of help with the same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50522677/how-can-i-access-edit-the-html-file-on-shopify/61237301#61237301). I see the HTML under inspection but for the life of me I cannot find the code in the liquid files of Shopify. I am on a free trial of Shopify, is that the problem? From my research it should be in either theme.liquid under layout or header.liquid under sections.

If you look at the link below, I want to remove BKLYN on the upper left.

Example of template: BROOKLYN

[image: Example of template: BROOKLYN]

Inspection: the HTML I want to edit

[image: Inspection: the HTML I want to edit]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which version of Brooklyn theme you have but if it's the latest one (16.0.2), you can find the code you're referring to in `sections/header.liquid`, lines 139-167. If you comment out these lines you'll get rid of the logo.